# the pulsar send look like succeed but really not when the grpc and pulsar in python?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc, apache-pulsar

When I use grpc and pulsar in python3:

1. if I import pulsar first and grpc second, the pulsar.send will work fine and I can consume the info.
2. if I import the grpc first and the pulsar after, the pulsar.send won't raise any error, but it won't send the message to the pulsar server and I cant consume the info.

The code is so simple:

```py
# The sequence below will give a different result.
import grpc
from pulsar import Client, Producer

client = Client('pulsar://pulsar-broker.pulsar.svc.cluster.local')

producer = client.create_producer('persistent://10001001/default/my_log')

msg_id = producer.send(('Hello, Pulsar!').encode('utf-8'))

print(f"the messsage_id: {msg_id}")

producer.close()
client.close()
```

Below are the version infos.

```sh
bash-4.4# python3 -m pip list | grep -E "grpc|pulsar"
grpcio                    1.46.3
grpcio-health-checking    1.46.3
grpcio-tools              1.46.3
pulsar-client             2.10.0
```

I want to read the code, but the pulsar client is in C++ and I don't understand C++.

What's the reason for the difference in behavior with the change in import order? And how do I fix it?

Comment: If everything works fine if you import pulsar first and grpc after, why not just keep the import statements in this order? Why do you want to import grpc first?

Comment: i want the truth

Comment: Do you have any debug logs or warnings from when the issue occurs?